# How would you say "Sorry I am only beginning to learn German"?

Tags: translation, phrase-request, grammaticality

What would be a good way to say "I'm sorry I am only beginning to learn German".

I usually say:

> Entschuldigung, mein Deutsch ist schlecht.

But that is not a very positive way to start a conversation.

Is this grammatically correct:

> Es tur mir leid, ich fange an Deutsch zu lernen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could translate "I've just recently started learning German" (almost) literally. There a couple of possibilities to translate *just recently*. A few examples:

> Ich habe kürzlichst erst angefangen Deutsch zu lernen.
>   Ich habe erst kürzlich angefangen Deutsch zu lernen.
>   Ich habe vor Kurzem erst angefangen Deutsch zu lernen.

<sub>The first version is restricted to some regions of Germany though.</sub>

Your sentence is not really wrong, though. "Ich fange an", however, is either present or future.

> Ich fange *gerade* an. (I'm starting right now.)
>   Ich fange *morgen* an. (I'm starting tomorrow.)

But you probably want to say that you've already started, so you should go with Present Perfect.

<sub>It's important to mention that the tenses are very different in German, although these simple examples suggest they're equal.</sub>

Comment: Sound's funny, better: Ich habe erst kürzlich angefangen Deutsch zu lernen.

Comment: @Kitana Danke. Hab's mit aufgenommen.

Comment: Im mündlichen Sprachgebrauch würde ich eher "Ich habe erst **vor kurzem** angefangen Deutsch zu lernen" empfehlen.

Answer (score 5):

I would translate it to:

> Entschuldigen Sie bitte. Ich fange gerade erst an, Deutsch zu lernen.